# Setting up JCup and JFlex under Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, jflex

I need to configure JCup and JFlex under Eclipse somehow. I have found that:

http://itee.uq.edu.au/~comp4403/assignments/Eclipse-Setup.html?print=1

and done almost everything but I do lack `build-cup.xml` and`build-flex.xml` which are necessary later

```
Under tab Main for Buildfile browse workspace and from within your assignment 2 project select A2 and then select "build-cup.xml" and then OK
```

How can I do set this up? I just need the simplest way to use JCup and JFlex

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar assignment. However, to be honest I just used a text editor like Sublime Text 2 or Atom to manually write my `Parser.cup` and `Scanner.jflex` files in a text editor. There is simple syntax checking in both editors if you set the view to "Java". In my opinion this is the best way.

If you are adamant on using Eclipse, you can download:

http://cup-lex-eclipse.sourceforge.net/installation.html

Your question was less about installation hence my answer is a bit shorter.

Comment: In last two years the JCup project had got big boost(website looks different, some updates occured, it was dead when I had use it), so now I think it would be easier to achieve that today. At the time I failed this project and it dragged my mark half step down. Altough nice that you included this link in your message.